# JavaScript Reference Details

Tags: javascript, reference, alias

I know this topic has come up a few times, but I couldn't find a conclusive answer/confirmation to what JavaScript references actually are.

The fundamental concepts I know so far are mainly *reference variables* (a variable that stores a reference) and *Aliases* (a variable which translates to the same memory address).

When looking at this tutorial, the main take-away seems: https://medium.com/@naveenkarippai/learning-how-references-work-in-javascript-a066a4e15600

> When the compound value in a variable is reassigned, a new reference
> is created. In JavaScript, unlike in most other popular programming
> languages, the references are pointers to value stored in variables
> and NOT pointers to other variables, or references.

This sounds very similar to the concept of Aliases. I know you can't compare JavaScript with C++, but conceptually speaking.

**So let me sum up and tell me if I am right - or otherwise feel free to correct me:**

It does not point to another variable, but to its value == the variable holds the object itself?

```
let a = { a: 4 }
let b = a
```

Accessing a reference means simply calling the variable, as it pretty much holds the object itself - no dereferencing necessary. Assigning a reference will need to check the type of variable 'a' first to see if it is an object and then set up 'b' with 'a's target address.

So 'a' and 'b' are just Aliases for the same variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have "reference variables" or "alias variables" "variable aliases"<sup>1</sup>. All JS variables are independent, and they can hold arbitrary values of any type.

When we talk about *references* in JS, we mean reference *values*. Consider them to work like C++ `shared_ptr`s (except that garbage collection does not work by refcounting).

> It does not point to another variable, but to its value

Kinda, yes. Both variables hold a reference value that references the same object. The assignment `b = a` created a copy of the reference value. Reassigning `a` to a different value (whether it is a different reference, or a primitive value like a number or `null`) will not affect `b`.

> So 'a' and 'b' are just Aliases for the same variable.

No. At best, they are aliases for the same *object*, since they both reference the same memory location where the `{ a: 4 }` is stored. That memory location is not a variable though, it's allocated in managed memory.

<sub>1: Module imports are real aliases though. When you `import { example as local } from …`, then `local` identifier resolves to the same variable (memory location) as `example` in the module that exports it. Changing the value of the `example` variable is reflected in `local`. The `local` import cannot be assigned to, though.</sub>

Comment: That sounds a lot like reference variables again. Reference variables are variables that store a reference to an object.

Comment: Yes, but JS variables can store *any* JS value, not just a reference to an object, so it's not called a "reference variable". The "C++ type" of the variable is more like a discriminated union between `float64_t`, `shared_ptr<string>`, `bool`, `null`, and `shared_ptr<void>`.

Comment: OK. To get this right. Let's take Java for comparison. Variables there can hold primitive values or references to objects. The difference in JS is that it always stores references to any type? So it also stores a reference to a Number? Is that correct? Otherwise it would be pretty much the same as in Java.

Comment: No - Java, like C++, is statically typed. Every variable has a fixed type which means you can only assign values of that type in it, so there are "integer variables" (`int x`) or "reference variables" (`Object o`). In JS, the variable does not constrain the value, so all you can say is "`x` is a variable currently holding an integer" or "`o` is a variable currently holding a reference to an object". But apart from that, the handling of objects is very much the same in Java and JavaScript, in that you cannot allocate them yourself and store only references to them.

Comment: And no, you cannot have a reference to a number or a reference to a string in JS. At least not in a way that you can compare them by reference, your program can always only observe the immutable value.

Comment: OK @Bergi, I think I got your point now. It's probably more correct to refer to what I call "reference variables" in JS as "variables that currently hold a reference". :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247625/discussion-between-tweekz-and-bergi).